# How to trigger an Onkeydown event on a WebView

Tags: android, webview, onkeydown

I have an Android apllication which has a Webview Controller and i want to trigger an Onkeydown event to this Webview programatically from the wrapping activity.
How do I do this?

thanks in advance

kobi

Comment: Show what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

A WebView doesn't seem to send click events to an OnClickListener. If you want to achieve this behavior you can use either OnTouchListener or warp the webView in some component and process the click events there..

Answer (score 0):

You can override a Webviews on TouchEvent like this. :)

```
wv = new WebView(getActivity()){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        td.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
};
```

And you can hand of the oNKeyDown event from the wrapping Activity to the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

> ```
>   @Override
> public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
>     if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
>         webview.goBack();
>         return true;
>     }
>     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
> }
> ```